# the installation tutorial of couchbase on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, server

I hope to install couchbase to ubuntu server 12.04.
Is there any tutorial?
I try to find but no result

your comment welcome

Answer (score 2):

The best way to install Couchbase Server is to download it.  To do so just [select the server platform of your choice](http://www.couchbase.com/download).  Once downloaded, open terminal, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the folder where the file was downloaded, and run the command(s) below:

For 64bit

```
sudo dpkg -i couchbase-server-enterprise_x86_64_2.1.0.deb
```

For 32bit

```
sudo dpkg -i couchbase-server-enterprise_x86_2.1.0.deb
```

For instructions, see the [Couchbase docs](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-getting-started-install-ubuntu.html), or the [Manual](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.1.0/)